# TypeScript wrong generic type parameter inference/calculation, what is going wrong?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

[Online Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsA8AVAjAGihgJgD4oBefLKCAD2AgDsATAZ3wKgH4oAKQq2hiwqcowAE4JoALigAzVMwgBKKDPkpFAbgCwAKFCQoAQXogAYgnoBjYAEsA9vTI8AdG6QykplaRJeQOvrg0AAiELK29BCMmMEk5BjB-HRMrJaM4ZHRIuqKqqISEIEG0ABy9sClCCjoiZDx+Ek0KULpmVGMelA5ChBd+XXQzYKs9NUo-Vy5fbrdMuKSxUlGADIVAPKymA0AShBW9mIx-ngYRIF6JVAAwo7MCzaHzgDeUFEA7q7uYgDmzJ7eAEgKAAXyWhlu9HuEkeYiMYjESGB5HhiJAaEh0IQsPOlySmIewEOK1sAGsIABlWwAWzAKAgg0YAAUxPYwGR+gAfG53QmHVFIrk8qF8sRCsY1IVtCIdcHQEwgdbAAAWEDEVNp9MZLLZzn8cqgGrpDOCzNZ7PIBJhRLEJPJRq1pp17O5CqVqvVNON2vNBudYXk1WAetMBtumpoPt15Ge-RKHBkDpNkDNbMC3QygZQwATUH94SQQfTUDEEEQtlLjFzACN7PZ6V4oNyJShAmC8YYoxbDV7HSnnU2eRHqF2DQBVeglVPd6GRH4XIKdp3mkn3ZyrDZbLu4xfQCdT52r4MohFItD75dsncd6CH2xrhKXsBHwcX-sr+-AMO863EsmU3tk2iZ1BjQfoMGSEZhSxWE7QAiMuz0BoIOGVJoNFAUQEmKAAEkRS8KwgMwABtMZqWrNUAF0iH6GQUIENCrWxG1sLw+4CKIs5aKgfUb2MUx3TVJMu1A+iWlYN0VSEwDt2cDAFyuAA1VBbEYSSPQDQtszA2ZGkMVChGEp8cH6TSg0gtCFQsaw7EcJC5KaBihHU6SEKfbD4GQdA9mABAxHoUCzOzIg8Bcz03PfNlRLiEgDNYBYZm6bouE81A0CZJBEWpCA6DEZg0CC4AQqgYjqP6OY5F6bjpgNZSUFUqzLBsBx6EKnTukGCzDJk4zTILcy4v48wmts+h7MffSnIk0xrOauzdJSxA0p8vyAuCAr+uCvAVv86L6liqaCkkcqRFS9AMqynK1XywrioupBsty-LBiIGjdIq6ZuLqhqBKksQ2sGPBbtqlTGCY2D-za8DHPEnsIuA80TN0wquum4abJa8a9KGQ7wZtOCjMisAPKW9ATu6Ha1sgDasyKpGkqSvG-3tHqib2iA3oZg7YYSk7Fq89LMoeq68pprS6ZKsr3vyT7dJkb61JmkaWoB4Igc2oqQfqxhZtGpn-o19rsdRuHvV65GNZNxqMfm5CYag3WWv17DeblqAFf1uDVcgdXaZ3JTQcGExGCh3TOsGwmEd1blpSyRh6agFHBvzWnB1jjosYDOOxaDbmoNd5LE8twbrbmsbpa4cpKnGWJ6hNguGZEBXHccfXvYgX3xc5xuZDOwXLqenOtsl7uPqqt2Eq11Tw2NEcn0wE2Z-pOeiYaBWg6YUOOuIgAiEod8ohOMF3zNxYPpCp8YLsF8G2SEkX+xh0Qhb3dBpfI3nri3bEqDI+nF3CjVV6AaAAsplUkMAkBWGVNfJkJsuxHgaLGXSxF2SRCgOSEA9hZB5kovLQO88mSoOom2S+d57jpRNuQoqzg4GDTfFHZ8n4AHHTdnQw6CDmEv2mCbMBYgIFQJgYQogxFMHYKgHwgR0DYFEEonzSqGhEpJXmIAt2NU+IYEKFZXopQIAADc1Q30OrWesEAvDIXroUEQ-h8hRAMWIA0uj7HrDhKYbYckTZ2LVCILxYh8i8V0LIZWjgoBgHNJQ5OH57hEG4P0ewpIZBOLVC4hUmAtEzR0fowxCtqHpVeiFOJMgmR6CUEUqAyDuill8v5KA9g2x6BoGAQ4wZT7mTCWybguByn9CMDICpSUSgyAAEJ1gbPQBOlSywIArNEFRkgJlQFadmbgpSoAmLGd06WkzqlOEnidEECcDn9CGX0k6gzDTiDnAspZwAVkyFnPQH4mzG4lhyqtKAO9VQ1HsDvYs3Qjm6QBd0a4pzpbnIpJcx51yNZ3KgA8p5-SGZVPeTvd4hwUCMF+fsw5CcQigoZuCyFPwcX9BgPigZwRExEoWaWcslY5kd36ACkEShAhAA)

Full Code:

```
type Equal<T1, T2> = T1 extends T2 ? (T2 extends T1 ? true : false) : false;
type AnyFunction = (...a: any) => any;
type Defined<Type> = Type extends undefined ? false : true;
type NotNull<Type> = Type extends undefined
  ? false
  : Type extends null
  ? false
  : true;
type ALotOf<T> = Record<any, T>;

type Constructor = { new (...args: any): any };
type ConstructorArray = Array<Constructor>;
type ConstructorLikeSimpleTypedProp =
  | ConstructorArray
  | Constructor
  | null
  | undefined;
type AnyOtherSimpleTypedProp = any;
type SimpleTypedProp = ConstructorLikeSimpleTypedProp | AnyOtherSimpleTypedProp;
type PropDefault = any;
type ComplexTypedProp = {
  type?: SimpleTypedProp;
  default?: PropDefault;
  required?: boolean | null;
};
type TypedProp = SimpleTypedProp | ComplexTypedProp;
type UntypedProp = string;

type TypedPropList = ALotOf<TypedProp>;
type UntypedPropList = Array<UntypedProp>;

type PropList = TypedPropList | UntypedPropList;
type ConstructorLikeSimpleTypedPropType<
  T extends ConstructorLikeSimpleTypedProp
> = T extends ConstructorArray
  ? InstanceType<T[number]>
  : T extends Constructor
  ? InstanceType<T>
  : any;
type AnyOtherSimpleTypedPropType<T extends AnyOtherSimpleTypedProp> = T;

type ValidAnyOtherDefault<
  Type extends SimpleTypedProp,
  Default extends AnyFunction
> = Type extends AnyOtherSimpleTypedProp
  ? Equal<ReturnType<Default>, AnyOtherSimpleTypedPropType<Type>> extends true
    ? Equal<Parameters<Default>, []>
    : false
  : false;
type ValidAnyFunctionDefault<
  Type extends SimpleTypedProp,
  Default extends AnyFunction
> = Type extends AnyFunction
  ? Equal<ReturnType<Default>, ReturnType<Type>> extends true
    ? Equal<Parameters<Default>, Parameters<Type>>
    : false
  : ValidAnyOtherDefault<Type, Default>;
type ValidConstructorLikeDefault<
  Type extends SimpleTypedProp,
  Default extends AnyFunction
> = Type extends ConstructorLikeSimpleTypedProp
  ? Equal<
      ReturnType<Default>,
      ConstructorLikeSimpleTypedPropType<Type>
    > extends true
    ? Equal<Parameters<Default>, []>
    : false
  : ValidAnyFunctionDefault<Type, Default>;
type ValidFunctionConstructorDefault<
  Type extends SimpleTypedProp,
  Default extends AnyFunction
> = Type extends FunctionConstructor
  ? true
  : ValidConstructorLikeDefault<Type, Default>;
type ValidTypeAndDefault<
  Type extends SimpleTypedProp | undefined,
  Default extends PropDefault | undefined
> = Defined<Default> extends true
  ? Default extends AnyFunction
    ? NotNull<Type> extends true
      ? ValidFunctionConstructorDefault<Type, Default>
      : Equal<Parameters<Default>, []>
    : false
  : true;
type ValidComplexTypedProp<T extends ComplexTypedProp> = ValidTypeAndDefault<
  T["type"],
  T["default"]
>;
type ValidTypedProp<T extends TypedProp> = T extends ComplexTypedProp
  ? ValidComplexTypedProp<T>
  : T extends SimpleTypedProp
  ? true
  : false;
type MarkEachTypedProp<P extends TypedPropList> = {
  [p in keyof P]: ValidTypedProp<P[p]>;
};
type ValidPropList<P extends PropList> = P extends UntypedPropList
  ? true
  : P extends TypedPropList
  ? false extends MarkEachTypedProp<P>[keyof MarkEachTypedProp<P>]
    ? false
    : true
  : false;
type TrueAnyFalseNever<T extends boolean> = T extends true ? any : never;
type NeverOrAny<T> = T extends never ? never : any;
function prop<P extends PropList>(
  ok: NeverOrAny<TrueAnyFalseNever<ValidPropList<P>>>,
  o: P
): P {
  return o;
}
export default prop(1, {
  A: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default(): boolean {
      return true;
    },
  },
  B: {
    type: String,
    default(): string {
      return "hello";
    },
  },
  C: {
    type: String,
    default(): string {
      return "world";
    },
  },
  D: {
    type: String,
  },
  E: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

I have no ideas what is going wrong......

**I think the type of the first parameter of `prop()` function should be calculated to be `any`, but it came to be `never`.**

I am looking for a functionality in TypeScript similar to "self-consstraint". That is to say, when there is only one function parameter, let TypeScript infer the generic type base on the argument, and it's also required that the generic type must satisfy some type constraints based on itself.

For exmaple, in the code I 've posted, every `type` field has a `Constructor` type, if there is a `default()` function besides the `type` field, the default function must return the same `InstanceType` according to its brother `type` field. Additionally,

**different `type` field can has different `Constructor` type.**

**So simple type like `Record<any, Type<T> | TypeAndDefault<T>>` just doesn't work, because `T` means the same type across all `type` fields.**

I just can't find a suitable type to express these rules, so I built an extra type as a "checker", it checks the generic type inferred by TypeScript, if all the rules are satisfied, the "checker" type will be `any`, or the "checker" type will be `never`.

In the code I've posted here, in the definition of function `prop()`, `ok` parameter has the "checker" type, `o` parameter has the `P` type. If the `P` type satisfies all the rules, the caller can use any value as the `ok` argument, no errors; but if the `P` type doesn't satisfy all the rules, the `ok` parameter type will become `never`, no matter what value the caller uses as the `ok` argument, it will be a Compile Error, so the caller can know there is something wrong with the `o`  argument he passes.

According to the results of my previous tests, `MarkEachTypedProp<P>` type works well. It maps every top level field in `o` argument to `true` type, the problem is the conditional type: `false extends MarkEachTypedProp<P>[keyof MarkEachTypedProp<P>] ? false : true` here:

```
type ValidPropList<P extends PropList> = P extends UntypedPropList
  ? true
  : P extends TypedPropList
  ? false extends MarkEachTypedProp<P>[keyof MarkEachTypedProp<P>]
    ? false
    : true
  : false;
```

`false extends MarkEachTypedProp<P>[keyof MarkEachTypedProp<P>] ? false : true` is calculated to be `false` ! So later `ok` parameter type becomes `never` !

**This can be proved by the following steps:**

**In the playground, change the `false` in the #101 line to `true`, then the error just disappears.**

Comment: Hmm, If your code example is too big for Stack Overflow then there's a good chance not a [mre].  Please consider trying to reproduce with fewer lines of code so that it can be posted in plain text in the question body.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve with the NeverOrAny type? What would be the example where the first parameter of Prop is never? And as the warning states, ok is not being used. Why do you actually need it?

Comment: @BrunoMarotta I am looking for a functionality in TypeScript similar to "self-consstraint". That is say, when there is only one function parameter, let TypeScript infer the generic type base on the argument, and its also required that the generic type must satisfy some type constraint based on itself. For exmaple, in the code I 've posted, every `type` field has a Constructor type, if there is a `default()` function besides the type field, the default function must return the same InstanceType according to its brother `type` field. <continue...>

Comment: @BrunoMarotta <continue...> Additionally, different `type` field can has different Constructor type. I just can't find a suitable type to express these rules, so I built an extra type as an "checker", it checks the generic type inferred by TypeScript, if all the rules are satisfied, the "checker" type will be `any`, or the "checker" type will be `never`. In the code I've posted here, `ok` parameter has the "checker" type, `o` parameter has the `P` type, if the `P` type satisfies all the rules, the caller can use any value as the `ok` argument, no errors; <continue...>

Comment: @BrunoMarotta <continue...> but if the `P` type doesn't satisfy all the rules, the `ok` parameter type will becomes `never`, no matter what value the caller uses as the `ok` argument, it will be an Compile Error, so the caller can know there is something wrong with the `o` argument he passes.

Comment: @BrunoMarotta According to the results of my prevous tests, `MarkEachTypedProp<P>` type works well. It maps every field in `o` argument to `true` type, the problem is the conditional type: `false extends MarkEachTypedProp<P>[keyof MarkEachTypedProp<P>] ? false : true` in the definition of type `ValidPropList<P>` is calculated to `false`. **This can be proved by the following steps: In the playground, change the `false` in the #101 line to `true`, then the error just disappears.**

Comment: I think there is two typo errors (that do not solve the full problem.).
A,B,C,D,E looks to be instance of ComplexTypedProp, if it is, the A.required and E.required should be A.require and E.require (without d)

Comment: I found that your 
type IsAnyNotNull = NotNull<any>; //=== boolean.which is quite strange, and would have side effect.

type IsAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? true : false; type NotNull<Type> = true extends IsAny<Type> ? true :  Type extends undefined ? false : Type extends null ? false : true;

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! I've add more details to the question, so I can post the full code here now. The full code is available now.

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER Thank you for pointing out the mistakes! I've fixed those mistakes, updated the code and the playground link, and also posted the full code here. But unfortunately, just as you said, the error still exists. There must be something else causing the error. And, I can't find definition of type `IsAnyNotNull` you mentioned, could you please clarify further more?

Comment: a few more remarks here [playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0bMGw)

Comment: @TanTelephone - Coming back to the NeverOrAny, aren't you mixing up Never with Undefined? If the first parameter may or not be filled, than it is something or undefined and not never. Never is used for return functions or parameters that you are sure will never happen. Furthermore I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve. I believe you are overcomplicating the problem and trying to solve something with type checking that can be only solved on runtime, as your parameter can be any or nothing. In that sense, I hope you the best of luck, but I won't be able to support you any more

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER Thank you very much for your patience to check and remark on my code. First of all, after long deep-digging, I've found it's a WebStorm's bug. In my old code, `ok` paramter should really be of `never` type, but WebStorm thinks it should be of `any` type, so things just get confused. Additionally, as you reminded, the type challenge part in my old code was indeed not robust enough, I have updated it to make it strong enough, and everything is on track now. I appeciate your kindness and patience.